# Most efficient way for process string escaping - Scala

Tags: scala, escaping, coding-efficiency

I'm using these 2 ways of processing string escaping a lot in the code:

1.

```
if (Seq("\\", "{" , "\"", "\"\"").exists(str.contains)) {
      str.replace("\"","").
        replace("{","-").
        replace("\\", "-").
        replace("\"\"","-")
    }
```

2. 

```
if (Seq("|", "\"").exists(str.contains)) s""""${str.replace("\"", "\"\"")}"""" else str
```

It runs inside a Spark cluster and the execution time is very important.
Is that the best way of doing that? Is there a better, more efficient way to do that?

Comment: this is plain Scala code so you would need to use an UDF if you want to use it in Spark. For the best performance try to use spark sql functions: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/sql/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided is some thing like this:

> Given some banned strings such as ["a", "b", "c"], if my string contains either of these string, go replace all the "a"s and "b"s and "c"s

So actually the checking part is redundant (I mean this part `Seq(...).exists(...)`), it doubles your complexity in cases that your string contains those banned strings. If you want to do it using scala functions and UDFs, I suggest you do this:

```scala
str
  .replaceAll("[{,\\\\,\"\"]", "-") // this means if you found either of {, \\, ", replace it with -
  .replaceAll("\"", "") // and if you found ", replace it with empty string
```

You can also chain 2 `regexp_replace` calls which is from spark APIs, you can choose between either of these 2.

Comment: And what about the second processing that I wrote?

Comment: @idanahal does it operate on the same string? If yes, you can just use another `.replaceAll` right after. And if not, it's much like the approach I proposed, `replaceAll("\"", "\"\"")`.